# 'showing' a facebook fb:dialog

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

i want to use facebook's fb:dialog tag to display a simple pop-up form for the user to fill in. but i want to show that dialog using javascript (in the ondone handler of an ajax request).

is this possible? i took a stab in the dark and tried document.getElementById('dialog_id').show() but show() is not a method.

alternatively there is the FBJS Dialog class but as far as i can tell you can only use it to create simple alert/confirm style dialogs. if someone knows of a way to put arbitrary content in them then that may also solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put arbritrary content inside of an FBJS dialog box.

First, store some arbitrary fbml in an fb:js-string tag:

```
<fb:js-string var="whatever">
<!-- HTML/fbml here -->
</fb:js-string>
```

then in fbjs do:

```
(new Dialog()).showMessage('title',whatever);
```

Comment: thanks! (i had just found the answer in fb's dev wiki and was just posting my own response).

Comment: @Tihorn, FBJS only exists inside of FBML. Outside of FBML, you can use any dialog library you want, such as jQuery's: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

figured it out.

buried in http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS/Examples/Dialogs is the answer.

basically you create a `<fb:js-string>` element with your form contents and then specify that string as the contents of the Dialog with the showChoice() method.

here is the relevant example:

```
<a href="#" id="dialog_body" onclick="var dialog = new Dialog().showChoice('Important Dialog', dialog_color, 'Okay', 'Nevermind');
dialog.onconfirm = function() {
  var color = document.getElementById('dialog_color_select').getValue();
  document.getElementById('dialog_body').setStyle({background: color});
};
return false;">
A dialog that changes your colors...</a><br />

<fb:js-string var="dialog_color">
<b>What color would you like this set to be?</b><br />
<select id="dialog_color_select">
<option value="transparent">Default</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
</fb:js-string>
```